# Device Activity Monitor in iOS doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, wwdc, parental-control

I have faced a problem with Screen Time API in iOS. I have successfully authorised using `AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization`, I have checked status using `AuthorizationCenter.shared.authorizationStatus`, but the problem is with `DeviceActivityCenter`.

In my ViewModel I have a function, that I'm calling after checking Authorisation Status:

```
func startMonitoringAccordingSchedule() {
        let schedule = DeviceActivitySchedule(intervalStart: DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0), intervalEnd: DateComponents(hour: 23, minute: 59), repeats: true)

        let center = DeviceActivityCenter()
        do {
            try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)
            print(" Success with Starting Monitor Activity")
        } catch {
            print(" Error with Starting Monitor Activity: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
    }
```

The problem is that with Succeed Authorisation, with Status = Approved, this function doesn't work, `try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)` fails and it goes to the catch block.

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution occasionally! The problem with `try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)` is that it can work only after selecting apps to block. If you try to start monitoring before you select apps - it won't work. At least this is what I found.

Comment: I call ```try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule)``` in my app ```didFinishLaunchingWithOptions``` before selecting apps just fine, but maybe they changed the api its been almost 2 years

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the DeviceActivityCenter() on which day -
Try:

```
DateComponents(hour: startHour, minute: startMinutes, weekday: day)
```

Comment: I did not add the weekDay component. It works fine most of the time but I am not getting the interval end callback sometimes. Will the missing weekDay component be a reason for it ?

Comment: @AkilanCB Yes, maybe. 
Try setting the day.
What is the error you see when not setting the day?
And after setting the day do you still get an error?

Comment: I'm not getting errors. I am able to register schedule without weekDay and it works fine most of the time. But I have noticed that in some case, the intervalDidEnd is not called as expected on the schedule end.

Comment: For me, when I set it with the day component this works @AkilanCB

And the question said:
"
The problem is that with Succeed Authorisation, with Status = Approved, this function doesn't work, try center.startMonitoring(.daily, during: schedule) fails and it goes to the catch block.
"
So he is getting an error